# Is it possible to extract image from text with jQuery or JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Good day, I'm trying to make an article content with `ckeditor`. Here is an example from my input.

```
<p>I have two images&nbsp;<img alt="" src="http://localhost:84/lf//assets/images/commingsoon.png" style="height:225px; width:225px" />&nbsp;and this&nbsp;&nbsp;<img alt="" src="http://localhost:84/lf//assets/images/article2.jpg" style="height:91px; width:122px" /></p>
```

As you can see there are two images, and i want to the first image as my thumbnail. for now, i just want to extract it .

The result from extract is something like this

```
http://localhost:84/lf//assets/images/commingsoon.png
```

---

```
var myString = '<p>I have two images&nbsp;<img alt="" src="http://localhost:84/lf//assets/images/commingsoon.png" style="height:225px; width:225px" />&nbsp;and this&nbsp;&nbsp;<img alt="" src="http://localhost:84/lf//assets/images/article2.jpg" style="height:91px; width:122px" /></p>';
var result = (someprosess)
```

Comment: Have you tried this $(img).attr('src');

Comment: For more clarification, set an `img` variable first. `var img = $("img")[0]` would grab the first image, and `[1]` would grab the second. Then you can do `var imgSrc = $(img).attr("src")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `find()`, `first()` and `attr()` to access the URL of the first image from your string.

```js
var myString = '<p>I have two images&nbsp;<img alt="" src="http://localhost:84/lf//assets/images/commingsoon.png" style="height:225px; width:225px" />&nbsp;and this&nbsp;&nbsp;<img alt="" src="http://localhost:84/lf//assets/images/article2.jpg" style="height:91px; width:122px" /></p>';
var result = $(myString).find('img').first().attr('src');
console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use either `JavaScript` or `jQuery` to search for the first instance of an image and parse out its src

As an example, using jQuery (if there is always going to be an image in the content)

```
var imgPointer = $('body').find('img');
var imgSrc = imgPointer[0].attr('src');
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with a solution using `jQuery`

```js
console.log($('p').find('img:first').attr('src'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>I have two images&nbsp;<img alt="" src="http://localhost:84/lf//assets/images/commingsoon.png" style="height:225px; width:225px" />&nbsp;and this&nbsp;&nbsp;<img alt="" src="http://localhost:84/lf//assets/images/article2.jpg" style="height:91px; width:122px" /></p>
```

Hope this will help you.